# Bindy - Apache Camel. Can a position (column) be ignored while unmarshaling CSV?

Tags: apache-camel, bindy

I am using camel-bindy to unmarshall a CSV to Java Object. Is it possible to ignore a particular column?
Consider following example, I don't want to map column 3 (Address). Please let me know if there is a way to do so. In reality I have more than 10 columns in my CSV that I want to ignore.

Example :- 
**CSV File:**

```
 Header   : Name,Mobile,Address
 Data Row : Rabbit,007,Rabbit Hole
```

**Bindy mapping in Java class:**

```
@CsvRecord(separator = "," , skipFirstLine = true) 
public class Contacts {

@DataField(pos = 1, trim=true)
private String name;

@DataField(pos = 2, required = true, trim=true) 
private Long Mobile;
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot skip a column. Bindy iterates through every token and checks if there is an associated data field, see [BindyCsvFactory](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-bindy/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/dataformat/bindy/BindyCsvFactory.java):

```
// Get DataField from model
DataField dataField = dataFields.get(pos);
ObjectHelper.notNull(dataField, "No position " + pos + " defined for the field: " + data + ", line: " + line);
```

The only solution is to define a class attribute that is just ignored:

```
@DataField(pos = 1)
public String ingoreMe;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I looked at BindyCsvFactory before posting the question. But I was hoping that there must be another way or a workaround for my requirement. I tried to move to BeanIO but there it seems the header cannot be easily skipped like in Bindy. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The latest version supports **skipField**

**@CsvRecord(separator = ",",skipField =true)**